# Show only weeks in Full Calendar jQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using the FullCalendar Plugin available at http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

I want a view which shows only weeks for the whole year. The headings must be W1, W2, W3... until W52. There is no need of time or day. My project schedules are by week rather than by date and time.

Is there any view available to show something like this?

Many Thanks

Comment: May be available as a fork. See here: https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=871

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @Ciro, no unfortunately. I ended up building my own calendar. I realized I really didn't need the FullCalendar plugin. A simple HTML table with 52 columns and a few calculations will do

Comment: I ended up by loading an 'Agenda' view with 365 days with all days hidden except mondays.

Answer (score 0):

These are the only official avaiable Views:

[Fullcalendar Views](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/Available_Views/)

There are forks from the master project made by other developers that have year views.

But your specific problem no, sorry.